# React native call function on original component from modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-modal

How can I call a function from the root component in a modal that is displayed over a component?

My HomePage.js calls the component as follows:

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalVisible: false
    };
  }

 
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible});
  };

 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title = "Get Started" onPress = {this.toggleModal} style={{width:150, height:50}}/>
       <SignUpModal display = {this.state.isModalVisible}/>
       <Image
          style={{ width: 335, height: 356 }}
          source={require('../assets/images/PSHomePageMobile.png')}
        />
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

Then my modal is rendered as follows. My goal is that when the user clicks that they have an account, they'll be able to get navigated to the signInModal. To do that, I want to toggle the signUpModal off first.

```
const SignUpModal = (props) => {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');

    return(
        <Modal isVisible = {props.display}>
                <View style={styles.container2}>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>Sign Up</Text>
                        <View>
                                <Text style={styles.fieldTitle}>Have an account?</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.accent} onPress={()=>HomePage.toggleModal()}>Sign In</Text>
                        </View>      
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.fieldTitle}>First Name</Text>
                <TextInput
                        style={styles.textbox}
                        onChangeText={firstName => setFirstName(firstName)}
                        defaultValue={firstName}
                />

                <Button title="Sign Up"/>
                </ScrollView>
                </View>
        </Modal>
        );
}
    
export default SignUpModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a callback function to your modal like below

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalVisible: false
    };
  }

 
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible});
  };

 render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title = "Get Started" onPress = {this.toggleModal} style={{width:150, height:50}}/>
       <SignUpModal display = {this.state.isModalVisible} toggle={this.toggleModal}/>
       <Image
          style={{ width: 335, height: 356 }}
          source={require('../assets/images/PSHomePageMobile.png')}
        />
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

You can call this function inside the modal

```
<Button title="Sign Up" onPress={props.toggle}/>
```

Comment: Inside the modal if I do <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={props.toggle (without the this.) it works. Thanks!

Comment: sorry its a functional component, missed that, Updated the answer